# How to pass a value from one page to another with onclick event in AppMaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

I am Building an AppMaker App. I have a `ChainStores` **Data model** which
has a **One to Many** relation with a `Locations` **Data Model**

I have one page with a list of `ChainStores` and another page with a list of `Locations` which should be based on the `ChainStore` selected.

I would like to have my second page `Location` to show the data based on what
is clicked on the first page `ChainStores`.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#creating_and_editing_query_datasources), it said that:

> When you create a model, a query datasource is automatically created
>   with the same name as the model. Whenever, you change the model name,
>   any query datasource with the same name will also have its name
>   changed to match the new model name. You can create additional query
>   datasources for a model. In the model editor, click **Add >
>   Datasource**. A new datasource is created with a default name. Often
>   you will create additional query datasources because you want to have
>   different options selected for a single model such as having different
>   sort orders or different page sizes.
>
> To edit an existing query datasource, open the model editor for the
>   data source. Then expand the **Datasources** tree item and select the
>   datasource.

You can also try to this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/tutorials/work-with-data/#what_youll_build).

> This tutorial teaches you how to:
>
> - Create a data model and add fields to it. You learn data-related concepts—data models, fields, records, datasources, and data bindings.
> - Add form and table widgets to a page. You learn how to modify these widgets and how they work. You also learn the difference between
>     insert forms and edit forms.